# Unable to access members in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, private-members

I'm defining a class in javascript as

```
    Class = (function() {
    var privateFunction = function() { return "private"; }
    return { publicFunction: function() { return privateFunction("public"); } };
    )();
```

Here user can access **Class.publicFunction**, but not **Class.privateFunction**.

Now I want to provide the user an interface to extend this Class. So I added a public function extend.

```
    Class = (function() {
            var privateFunction = function() { return "private"; }
            return { 
                    publicFunction: function() { return privateFunction("public"); } 
                    extend: function(source) { 
                            dest=this;
                            for(var prop in source)dest[prop] = source[prop]
                    }
            };
    )();
```

My aim was to use the extend attribute as follows

```
    Class.extend({
            someFunc: function() { return privateFunction("hooray"); }
    });
```

and access it as

```
    Class.someFunc()
```

The problem I face is the call to the **privateFunction()** in the extended function **someFunc** is not available for it. I can understand that it is the problem of the scope, but, is there anyway to solve my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's a horrible violation of encapsulation, you could do what you describe by passing the function you want to add as a string and `eval`ing it in `extend`:

```
Class.extend({
        someFunc: 'function() { return privateFunction("hooray"); }'
});
```

and in the `extend` function, change

```
                        for(var prop in source)dest[prop] = source[prop]
```

to

```
                        for(var prop in source)dest[prop] = eval(source[prop])
```

Comment: thanks for you idea
i used it as

`for(var prop in source)dest[prop] = eval("temp="+String(source[prop]));`

Comment: will this give any problem anywhere. I'm working on linux. Will this be an issue in windows IE ?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.before = function(){return "public"};
this.publicFucntion = function(){privateFunction(this.before());}
```

Then just override this.before.